# Sequence no update for duplicate record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like as follows and I need to update 'SEQUENCE_NO' based on duplication record (SEQUENCE_NO). I need help on this:

Current table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID    |     TYPE_ID   |    CREATED_DATE    |   SEQUENCE_NO
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               1               24-APR-10            NULL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2               1               25-APR-10            NULL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
3               1               26-APR-10            NULL
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
4               2               22-APR-10            NULL
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
5               2               24-APR-10            NULL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
6               3               27-APR-10            NULL
```

Expecting result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID    |     TYPE_ID   |    CREATED_DATE    |   SEQUENCE_NO
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               1               24-APR-10            1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2               1               25-APR-10            2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
3               1               26-APR-10            3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
4               2               22-APR-10            1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
5               2               24-APR-10            2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
6               3               27-APR-10            1
```

SQL Query or PL/SQL program should be fine.

Comment: Try using RANK() over TYPE_ID

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
merge into the_table tb
using (
  select id,
         row_number() over (partition by type_id order by created_date) as rn
  from the_table
) t on (t.id = tb.id)
when matched then update
  set sequence_no = t.rn;
```

Apparently the `id` column is *not* your primary key (which you should have told us right from the start).

You can either find a unique combination of columns in the table to make the join between the merged table and the query or as a quick workaround (for Oracle) you can use the rowid to join the query and the merged table:

```
merge into the_table tb
using (
  select rowid as rid,
         row_number() over (partition by type_id order by created_date) as rn
  from the_table
) t on (t.rid = tb.rowid)
when matched then update
  set sequence_no = t.rn;
```

As you are apparently looking for a solution for Oracle **and** SQL Server (which again you didn't mention in your original question) the above will not work with SQL Server (it does not have anything similar to Oracle's rowid).

To make this work reliably in both DBMS, you **have** to find a primary key for the table.

Comment: Thank you for your query...but its showing error on "t.id = id.id".

Comment: @Srinivash: sorry, copy and paste error. Should be `t.id = tb.id`

Comment: yes...its working great in SQL Server...but not in oracle sql developer...I am facing following error:Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
*Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
           activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
*Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.

Comment: Then there is something you are not telling us: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/173f4/1 Btw: how did SQL Server come into this? In your question you are only talking about Oracle.

Comment: thanks for your reply and your query is working fine absolutely...but I am facing above error...can you help me on this error..thanks

Comment: @Srinivash - you seem to have rows with duplicate ID values. (In the SQL Fiddle above, try adding a second row with ID 6, and 'build schema' will get ORA-30926). Your sample data suggests they are unique, and an ID column usually is, but would be enforced by a PK or UK as David suggested. If you're expecting it to be unique then you need to clean up the data, and preferably then put a constraint on the ID to prevent duplicates in the future.

Comment: @Srinivash: see my edit for a workaround. But you should *really* define a primary key on your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID,TYPE_ID,CREATED_DATE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY TYPE_ID ) AS SEQUENCE_NO
FROM Table_name
```

Try This
Let me know if its working or not

Comment: Hi, Sandeep, its not working bcoz, its missed the ORDER BY clause...and I want to update the field not for select

Comment: `UPDATE Table_name

SET RankCol = SubQuery.Rank

FROM

(

SELECT ID,TYPE_ID,CREATED_DATE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY TYPE_ID ORDER BY TYPE_ID) AS Rank

FROM Table_name

) SubQuery

INNER JOIN Table_name ON

SubQuery.ID = Table_name.ID

AND SubQuery.TYPE_ID = Table_name.TYPE_ID`
Will this work?
Just check and let me know